Is there a way to pass properties to display with Salt's service.show?
When you run systemctl show -pId,ActiveState,ActiveEnterTimestamp <service> you can have systemctl display only the properties requested.
Can you do this with salt <host> service.show <service>
The workaround is using cmd.run as
salt <host> cmd.run "systemctl show -pId,ActiveState,ActiveEnterTimestamp <service>".

No, the function takes no arguments to do that.
However, you could filter the output yourself:
salt <host> service.show salt-minion --out=json \
    | jq '.[] | {Id,ActiveState,ActiveEnterTimestamp}'

{
  "Id": "salt-minion.service",
  "ActiveState": "active",
  "ActiveEnterTimestamp": "Wed 2024-08-14 09:36:22 UTC"
}

Or with similar manipulation in a template:
{%- set info = salt["service.show"]("salt-minion") -%}
{%- for key in ("Id","ActiveState","ActiveEnterTimestamp") %}
{{ key }}={{ info.get(key) }}
{%- endfor %}

Id=salt-minion.service
ActiveState=active
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Wed 2024-08-14 09:36:22 UTC


not directly.
but using jq you can parse the full data it shows down to just what you want
such as for your example
salt <host> service.show <service> --out=json | jq '.<host> | "ID=\(.Id)","ActiveState=\(.ActiveState)","ActiveEnterTimestamp=\(.ActiveEnterTimestamp)"'
